# RestSharp Returning Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

I am having an issue and think I may be missing something with RestSharp.
I am authorizing and getting back a cookie just fine... see below. But then when I call to get the data it returns unauthorized. It works just fine in Postman but not in the code below. I am using a console app and I have tried to send the cookie via AddHeader, AddCookie, and just as a parameter. The responseLogin does contain the correct cookie. Any help would be great.

```
    Dim clientLogin = New RestClient("http://[URI to Authorize]............")
    Dim requestLogin = New RestRequest(Method.POST)

    requestLogin.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "[Username and password here.....]", ParameterType.RequestBody)
    Dim responseLogin As IRestResponse = clientLogin.Execute(requestLogin)




    Dim client = New RestClient("http://[URI to get data]............")
    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.GET)

    request.AddHeader("Cookie", responseLogin.Cookies(0).Value.ToString)
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")

    Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Cookie` header needs to contain the name and value for the cookie, e.g.

```
Dim authCookie = responseLogin.Cookies(0) ' Probably should find by name
request.AddHeader("Cookie", String.Format("{0}={1}", authCookie.Name, authCookie.Value))
```

However, [the documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies) (I've never used RestSharp personally) says that RestSharp has automatic support for cookies, so if you reuse the `RestClient` instance and set the `CookieContainer` you shouldn't need to do anything to handle the cookies manually (unless you want to, which in some cases may be preferable).

```
Dim client = New RestClient(New Uri("[Base URI...]"))
client.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer()

Dim requestLogin = New RestRequest("[login page path]", Method.POST)
requestLogin.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "[Username and password here.....]", ParameterType.RequestBody)
Dim responseLogin As IRestResponse = client.Execute(requestLogin)

Dim request = New RestRequest("[data api path", Method.GET)
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
```

You could probably just reuse the cookie container with different `RestClient` instances instead of reusing the `client`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on RestClient .NET framework 4.5.2 version.
It turns out you have to implement the IAuthenticator interface.

```
 public class MyAuth : IAuthenticator
{
    readonly string _password;
    readonly string _passwordKey;
    readonly string _username;
    readonly string _usernameKey;

    public MyAuth(string usernameKey, string username, string passwordKey, string password)
    {
        _usernameKey = usernameKey;
        _username = username;
        _passwordKey = passwordKey;
        _password = password;
    }

    public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
        => request
            .AddCookie(_usernameKey, _username)
            .AddCookie(_passwordKey, _password);
            //.AddParameter(_usernameKey, _username)
            //.AddParameter(_passwordKey, _password);
            
}
```

I did this and my request worked.